# Solving symmetric equations in three unknowns by reducing the number of unknowns from $3$ to $2$

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, roots

I'd like to solve the following system of three quadratic that has obvious symmetric in its structure,

$ x^2 + y^2 + xy = a^2 \tag{1}$

$ y^2 + z^2 + y z = b^2 \tag{2}$

$ z^2 + x^2 + zx = c^2 \tag{3}$

**My attempt:**

Multiplying $(1)$ by $b^2$ and subtracting $a^2$ times $(2)$ gives the homogeneous equation

$ b^2 x^2 + (b^2 - a^2) y^2 - a^2 z^2 + b^2 xy - a^2 y z = 0 \tag{4} $

Similarly, multiplying $(1)$ by $c^2$ and subtracting $a^2$ time $(3)$ gives

$ (c^2 - a^2) x^2 + c^2 y^2 + c^2 xy - a^2 z^2 - a^2 xz = 0 \tag{5}$

Assuming $x \ne 0$, then dividing $(4)$ and $(5)$ by $x^2$ yields

$ b^2 + (b^2 - a^2) u^2 - a^2 v^2 + b^2 u - a^2 u v = 0 \tag{6} $

$ (c^2 - a^2) + c^2 u^2 + c^2 u - a^2 v^2 - a^2 v = 0 \tag{7} $

where $u = \dfrac{y}{x}$ and $v = \dfrac{z}{x} $

Equation $(7)$ is nice in that it doesn't have the $uv$ term, so completing the squares in $u$ and $v$ gives

$ (c^2 - a^2) + c^2 ( u + \dfrac{1}{2} )^2 - a^2 ( v + \dfrac{1}{2} )^2 = \dfrac{1}{4} (c^2 - a^2) $

which reduces to

$ c^2 ( u + \dfrac{1}{2} )^2 - a^2 ( v + \dfrac{1}{2} )^2 = \dfrac{3}{4} (a^2 - c^2) \tag{8}$

Assuming $a^2 - c^2 \gt 0 $, then the solution of this equation is

$ u = -\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{K}{c} \sec \theta \tag{9} $

$ v = - \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{K}{a} \tan \theta \tag{10}$

where $K^2 = \dfrac{3}{4} (a^2 - c^2) $

Substituting $(9)$ and $(10)$ into $(6)$, gives a trigonometric equation involving $\sec \theta , \tan \theta , \sec^2 \theta, \tan^2 \theta, \sec \theta \tan \theta $.  This equation can be transformed into an equation involving just $\cos \theta, \sin \theta, \sin^2 \theta, \cos^2 \theta $ by multiplying it through by $\cos^2 \theta $.

The final shape of equation $(6)$ takes the form

$ A \cos \theta + B \sin \theta + C \cos(2 \theta) + D \sin(2 \theta) + E = 0 $

And there is a standard technique to solve this equation that uses the substitution $ t = \tan\left( \dfrac{\theta}{2} \right)$.  This transforms this trigonometric equation into a quartic (degree 4) polynomial in $t$.  Solutions $t$ can be found numerically using the well-known Newton's method, or a similar method, or even better using Bairstow's method, or can be computed exactly (also numerically) using the quartic root formulas.  If you're using Mathematica or Sage or a similar math app there are functions to compute the roots of any polynomial.

Once the roots $t$ have been computed, the corresponding $\theta$'s can be found by inverting the defining formula, and finally $u, v$ can be computed.  And finally $x$ can be computed from the original equations, and so can $y$ and $z$.

That's what I wanted to present as a possible way to solve this particular problem.

Your comments, hints, or additional information, and alternative solutions are appreciated.

Thank you all.

Comment: Sage (or sagemath) is giving (possibly through singular) the equation in $x$ of the shape $0=Ax^4 + Bx^2 +C$ after the elimination of $y,z$, where $$\begin{aligned}A &= 9(a^4  + b^4 + c^4 - a^2b^2 - a^2c^2 - b^2c^2)\ ,\\B &= 3(-2a^6 + 5a^4b^2 - 4a^2b^4 + b^6 - a^4c^2 + 3a^2b^2c^2 - 4b^4c^2 - a^2c^4 + 5b^2c^4 - 2c^6)\ ,\\C &= (a^2 - b^2 + c^2 + ac)^2 (a^2 - b^2 + c^2 - ac)^2\ ,\\&\text{ so that }\\B^2-4AC &=27(a+b-c)(b + c -a)(a + c - b)(a + b + c)(b - c)^2(b + c)^2 (a - b)^2 (a + b)^2\ .\end{aligned}$$Sage is already free, you can get it full (per one click sometimes on a linux box).

Comment: (If restricted to positive reals) __Hint:__ $\cos 120^\circ = - 1/2$. You want the Fermat point of a (hopefully acute angled) triangle.

Comment: @sirous I've undeleted the question.  If you have a comment or an answer, I would appreciate your input.